# Magento - Collection Filter by Array Keep Order

Tags: magento

Is it possible to filter a Magento collection using an array of id's **BUT** have the collection results ordered by the order of the id's passed to the filter.

For example:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                  ->getCollection()
                  ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array(
                       'in' => array(1, 3, 2),
                   ));
```

I would like the collection to have products in order, 1,3,2 so as when looping through the collection they come out in that specific order?

The only alternative i currently have is to manually create an array of products:

```
$productIds = array(1,3,2);
$collection = array();

foreach($productIds as $productId) {
    $collection[] = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
}
```

This obviously works but seems like an ugly way to do this.

is there a way to do this purely via magento collections?

Answer (score 12):

```
$productIds = array(1,3,2);

/**
 * Build up a case statement to ensure the order of ids is preserved
 */
$orderString = array('CASE e.entity_id');
foreach($productIds as $i => $productId) {
    $orderString[] = 'WHEN '.$productId.' THEN '.$i;
}
$orderString[] = 'END';
$orderString = implode(' ', $orderString);

/**
 * Filter the collection
 */
$productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('in' => $productIds));

/**
 * Apply the order based on the case statement
 */
$productCollection->getSelect()
    ->order(new Zend_Db_Expr($orderString))
```

Comment: Just perfect solution. Works great.

Answer (score 3):

Pretty old but a simple solution I found on stackoverflow is

```
$productIds = array(1,3,2);
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
            ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('in' => $productIds));
$products->getSelect()->order("find_in_set(entity_id,'".implode(',',$productIds)."')");
```

[from here on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13179933/3713817)

Answer (score 1):

You can load the collection before sorting it in PHP. Eg :

```
$result = array();
$productIds = array(1,3,2);
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('in' => $productIds))
    ->load();

foreach ($productIds as $productId) {
    if ($product = $collection->getItemById($productId)) {
        $result[$productId] = $product;
    }
}
```

Else, purely with collections, you should first pass by the `Zend_Db_Select` object of the collection, to be able to sort on expressions (what may not be possible with eg EAV based collections and calls to `addAttributeToSort` or `sortOrder`).
Then you can either use multiple `order` calls as stated in Gershon's answer, or use a single `order` with a generated `CASE WHEN THEN` statement. Knowing that it could depend on the maximum number of IDs you may have to filter on.

Answer (score 0):

This is a challenging question, here is a solution that should work:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                  ->getCollection()
                  ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array(
                       'in' => array(1928, 1930, 1929),
                   ))
           ->addAttributeToSort('entity_id = 1928', 'ASC')
           ->addAttributeToSort('entity_id = 1930', 'ASC')
           ->addAttributeToSort('entity_id = 1929', 'ASC')
           ;
```

Comment: Hi Gershon, thanks for the answer.  It makes sense with regards to the attributeToSort but the problem is that addAttributeToFilter example above is just an example, there could be an arbitrary number of elements in the array.  I guess i could loop over each element and call addAttributeToSort but thats then getting in to the territory where i started with the loop to create the collection as an array