# magento product collection with specific id

Tags: magento

i select products with

```
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('in' => $productIds));
```

how can i archieve that the collection is in the same order as the ids in  $productIds?

thanks

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
    $productIds = array(1,3,2);
    $products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
                ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('in' => $productIds));


    $products->getSelect()->order("find_in_set(entity_id,'".implode(',',$productIds)."')");

    foreach($products as $product)
    {
        echo $product->getEntityId();
        echo $product->getSku();
    }
```

See more @

- [Magento get a product collection in an arbitrary order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3990266/magento-get-a-product-collection-in-an-arbitrary-order)
- [How to select mysql rows in the order of IN clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4986731/how-to-select-mysql-rows-in-the-order-of-in-clause)

Comment: nice my solution was worse: $collection->getSelect()->order("(CASE e.entity_id WHEN $p1path[1] THEN 1 WHEN $p2path[1] THEN 2 WHEN $p3path[1] THEN 3 ELSE 0 END)");

Comment: @Renon Stewart:  you saved me days of my life. Thanks :D

Comment: wow greate soluions, work for me thanks @MagePal