# Magento order category products by SKU and words in product name

Tags: magento, magento-1.8

I've had a strange request from a client.

They want to order their products programmatically by SKU but have a certain three products (the three best-sellers) always appear first regardless of the SKU.

So it would be:
1. product 1
2. product 2
3. product 3
then the rest of the products ordered by SKU.

I know the below code will order the products by sku but I don't know how to alter it to achieve what I want.

The three products would be selected by mentioning a word in the products name e.g 'White' in King Size White Bed

```
$this->_productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('sku')
    ->setOrder('sku', 'asc')->load();
```

Can anyone give me some help please? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this kind of behaviour before. It's usually done a bit differently, by loading a collection of best seller or other pinned products that they're trying to upsell, and then the normal product collection for pagination. This functionality of collections would be encapsulated in blocks to make it nicer on the frontend. Would that be more suitable for you?

```
/**
 * Get Best Sellers
 */
/** @var Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection $bestSellersCollection */
$bestSellersCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$bestSellersCollection
    ->addFieldToFilter('name', array('like' => '%white%'))
    ->setPageSize(3)
    ->setOrder('name', Varien_Data_Collection::SORT_ORDER_ASC);

$bestSellerIds = array();
foreach ($bestSellersCollection as $bestSeller) {
    $bestSellerIds[] = $bestSeller->getId();
}

/**
 * Get Products excluding the best sellers.
 */
/** @var Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection $productCollection */
$productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$productCollection->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', array('nin' => $bestSellerIds))
    ->setOrder('sku', Varien_Data_Collection::SORT_ORDER_ASC);
```

If you're dead set on having a single collection, you may have some luck merging the logic from the following two answers.

[Magento: how to merge two product collections into one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5434996/magento-how-to-merge-two-product-collections-into-one)

[Magento - Collection Filter by Array Keep Order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11529833/magento-collection-filter-by-array-keep-order)